# trouble with fscanf when using structs

Tags: c, struct, scanf

```
typedef struct computer
{
char serialNumber[8];
int price;
int GBofRAM;
int GBofHardDrive;
}Computer;

Computer* readComputers(char* filename);


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

if(argc!=2){
    printf("Invalid number of arguments");
    return 1;
}
Computer* x=readComputers(argv[1]);
printComputers(x);

free(x);
return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
Computer* readComputers(char* filename)
{

Computer* cptr=malloc(sizeof(Computer)*6);
FILE* fp=fopen(filename, "r");
if(fp==NULL){
    printf("Failed to open file %s", filename);
    return;
}
//fread(cptr, sizeof(Computer), 6, fp);

fscanf(fp,"%s, %d, %d, %d", Computer->serialNumber, &Computer->price, &Computer->GBofRAM, &Computer->GBofHardDrive);

fclose(fp);  
return cptr;
```

I'm having issues getting this `fscanf()` to work correctly. it's saying it's missing an expression before `Computer->serialNumber` but I'm not sure why that's the case? I've tried looking on Tutorialspoint but that wasn't of too much help.

Comment: What is the "it" that's saying it's missing an expression? Is this a compiler error? If so, what's the *exact* error?

Comment: Also, don't post incomplete code. Mention the error and try to post a [mcve]

Comment: the code allocates enough memory for 6 instance of the struct, but only reads into one entry.  so this line: `fscanf(fp,"%s, %d, %d, %d", Computer->serialNumber, &Computer->price, &Computer->GBofRAM, &Computer->GBofHardDrive);`   should be: `if( 4 != fscanf(fp,"%7s, %d, %d, %d", cptr[0].serialNumber, &cptr[0].price, &cptr[0].GBofRAM, &cptr[0].GBofHardDrive) ) { // handle error}`  Notice the '7' so the serialNumber array cannot be overflowed.
`

Answer (score 4):

As per your code,

```
Computer->serialNumber
```

is an invalid statement. `Computer` here is a (user defined) data type. You cannot defererence that. You need to use `cptr` as the variable name, which you have defined.

Also, always check for the success of `malloc()` before using the returned pointer. Otherwise, in case if `malloc()` fails you'll be invoking undefined behavior by accessing invalid pointer.

Answer (score 2):

In function `Computer* readComputers(char* filename)`

```
Computer* cptr=malloc(sizeof(Computer)*6);
```

You have pointer to struct `cptr` use it to access struct's members .

Write `fscanf` like this-

```
while(fscanf(fp,"%7s, %d, %d, %d", 
        cptr->serialNumber, &cptr->price, &cptr->GBofRAM, &cptr->GBofHardDrive)==4){
       // do something with these variables
   }         //loop as OP has mentioned in comment
```

Also checking return of `fscanf`.

Comment: so doing it the way suggested prints out garbage like so: 10005 32 544 2359296� 83886080 21 205031368�ދ�v�X� 1001 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

when it's supposed to print out 6 different computers. any idea why this is?

Comment: @Geoff  How is data stored in your file ?

Comment: just a simple .txt file. It looks like this
10005 400
4 1000

there are 6 of those. After the 400 there is a newline

Comment: @Geoff  Then you will need a loop . You should have mentioned it . I have updated answer with loop . Please check it once.

Comment: Ohh. would a while((!feof)fp) just do fine, then? Even so, it should read the first set correctly, right? it only got the 10005 correct.

Comment: @Geoff  Then you have to change how you call your function. Or it will always return the last value in file only . If you want to print it ,do it inside this loop , so every line will be printed .

Comment: @Geoff  Don't ever use `while(!feof(fp))` . Put `fscanf` in loop as I did in answer .